# Need help on Jmeter Java API dynamically create .jmx file with certain actions as explained

Tags: java, api, jmeter

The Version i want to create is explained below:

Without using GUI ( Java API )

- Create a **HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder** ( **Workbench > Non-Test
  Elements > HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder** ) and start it Dynamically.
- Perform set of actions in Browser(I will hit this browser with a
  webdriver code to generate actions accordingly) with proxy settings
  in Browser, which i need to get **Test Plan > Thread Group >
  Recording Controller > Actions** dynamically.
- Once actions in Broswer is completed(i.e., execution of my Webdriver
  code is completed) need to stop **HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder**
  dynamically.
- And create the above **Test Plan > Thread Group > Recording
  Controller > Actions** as a **.jmx** file dynamically

Please help me with certain examples whether this way is possible or not using JMETER JAVA API.

Comment: Did you figure this out?  If not, I would like to work with you to solve it, since I have the same need.